# WEBpages to EXE

Tags: java, vb6, exe

**1) couple of HTML files in which javascript is embeded.....**

My Requirements

**1) I want my whole website to be in exe format  so that i can protect my javascript code.**

**2) or tell me how to open website inside the vb6 program ...so that i can build a exe. And yeah i want the webpages to use the Internet Explorer but i want only the titlebar.....nothing else in the window frame.**

**3) if you know any method to get it done through java ... then please give me the exact codes without any errors....i dont know coding that much ...i just started coding.**

**Note:** Please dont ask me  to use html2exe converter .....i tried using that but some javascript and html frames dont work. if you know any other software which can do the job correctly then please let me know. And please give detailed explanations in your vb codes .....i am a newbie in vb just started learning 3 days ago...

The idea:

**The whole idea is to make those webfiles act like a software. Like a standalone exe**

Any help would be aprreciated....I have been searching all over the net for 2 weeks.....please help

Thanks Friends

Looking forward for your replies

Regards

-Shubanki

Comment: Why are you keep voting that is not a real question? How to protect code is a real question and programming related!

Comment: is point 2 possible ????

Comment: is it possible to ask another question inside a question ...i am new to this site ( this site rocks )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure what you're asking could be achieved, but I'm also sure that nobody is going to write a complete solution for you just because you're new to programming. That's not how the world works.

It sounds like you want to write your software in HTML/JavaScript, but distribute it like a standalone program. This could theoretically be achieved with some kind of extracting program, where the executable would be bundled with all the HTML and JavaScript source code. The executable would read the files from within itself, save them temporarily elsewhere, and then invoke the system's default browser to open an index file. Then the temp files could be cleaned up when the program exited.

This should be relatively simple to do with vb6, although I have not programmed in vb6 for quite some time.

That being said, however, this is, in every way, a bad idea. First, vb6 is an outdated technology and is no longer supported. Second, you're adapting all of the shortcomings of a web application, and not taking advantage of any of the benefits, AND making your life harder by writing extra standalone code that won't work in many places. So you've taken a web application and made it less portable, where web applications are supposed to excel at portability; and you're still going to have to deal with the fact that it's *still a web application* no matter which way you build it -- your GUI will be harder to develop and be less rich than a desktop application, you'll have to deal with supporting multiple browsers, it'll be more painful to try and work with the machine the app is running on, **AND** you still won't be protecting your JavaScript, since there's *no way to completely protect your JavaScript*.

My suggestion to you is to learn VB.Net rather than VB6 and develop an *actual* desktop application, or (if your application is more comfortable on the web) just develop a web application, put it on the web, and let users load it with their web browsers.

Comment: thanks mr.carson myers, the problem is that i coded this like 3 yeras ago when i didnt know wat computers were ? :P.....i was thinking about the idea of a exe that temporarily extracts itself along with the html files in to temp folder  and opening the html with only a titlebar .... i not much concerened about the protection of my javascript code since the application was made for educational purpose. 
thanks again

Comment: and Friend as u suggested , i am looking forward to learning VB.net but just wanted to know is it as easy as vb6 ?? and also which languages are recommended to get a good job ...(i will soon have to look after my family)

Comment: .Net has a wide job market, but that's a different topic. I'm still not sure why this *needs* to be an executable -- why don't you just throw it online and distribute a shortcut? For example, in chrome I just clicked the file menu > Create application shortcuts... on this page, and it put an icon on my desktop with the SO logo, and it opens this page in a window with only the title bar. Or at _least_ make a web application that just launches the system default browser. But making a web page into an executable just doesn't seem right.

Comment: the web pages are in my pc not in internet ...i am nt uploading it...i wanna use it to teach an entire class about HTML. IT is a simple HTML program in which we type the html in a textbox and the output is shown in a adjacent iframe. i want it to be in a exe format so that i give to some1 easily.. i am nw thinking of making a program in vb6 which can open and show the webpages...but dont know hw to do that!!  thanks again for replying

Comment: and also i dont know how to make a web apllication that opens the default browser

Comment: i have another doubt is it possible that when u double click on index.html it opens in Internet Explorer with only the title bar ???

Comment: If you need to teach people to use HTML then why on earth would you want to pack it up in an executable to make it difficult for them to read? Just put in in a zip folder to give it out. If it's just HTML and javascript then you won't need a server to run it, and people should be able to extract the files and run and read them themselves.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't hide javascript**... it's a client side technology, so it must be visible all times to the client (the browser)

Even if you block the **Right Click**, we can see the **page source** and track all calls to the js files that page is using.

if you are so paranoid with protecting the javascript, the most you can do is **obfuscating and minimize it** to be harder to a human to read and understand it.

or, keep you source simple and **make calls to a Service** (WCF installed as a Windows Service is good and very fast for this, or a simple DLL that act as a Service) and use, for example, jQuery library to safely call it and retrieve parameters...

all you HTML should do is to present data, the CSS should do the visual part, and the jQUery only to grab a new set of results and fill up DOM elements.

That's what I would do... *if I was paranoid why protecting my code* :)

---

**Added**

OR, if it's only HTML and javascript... wrap that up in **Adobe AIR** and deploy it safely!

> [This is all what you need](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/develop/ajax/)

And you can target not only Windows, but Mac and Linux as well :)

Comment: I am more concerned with presenting my website as a software application. I can acheive the same result with visual basic but i dont know how to make some effects like that of css...and my friend it has html, javascript and css and some images ..thats it .. and thanks for replying so fast. i luv you people.

Comment: Mr.balexandre can Adobe air make a simple exe out of my html files...

Comment: I just looked up adobe AIR. I didn't know what it was before; I learned something new :)

Comment: Mr subanki, no, but it will create one file .air that can be installed and run if Adobe Air Runtime is installed on the client computer.

Download any Air App and you will see what it is: http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplatformruntimes/gallery/

Comment: i am Miss subanki...lol   
 
Mr subanki sounds so akward

Answer (score 0):

Even if you packaged your web site up into an executable with its own bundled browser, you would only be obfuscating your source.  A determined hacker could still retrieve your JavaScript.  If you want a closed-source executable, write a closed-source executable in a client-side programming language.  Like C, C++, or Java.

Making a web page into an executable is a gigantic leap backwards for functionality.  The executable will be **much** larger, less flexible, and hungrier for both RAM and CPU time.

Also, bolding your question does not make it easier to get an answer.

Comment: wow an answer in 15 mins ty dude...u ppl rock 
I designed the website so nicely that i dont think i can get the same graphic effects in any other language (according to my coding capabilities). And besides the website is merely 1 mb. And sorry for typing in bold letters.... i type a lot and people often dont like reading much ..so i made them bold..sorry